# Is pattern recognition NP-complete?

Tags: np, it.information-theory, computational-complexity

Hello,

is the problem of pattern recognition (for a given sequence of n numbers, find the shortest Turing machine with an alphabet of 42 elements that will output these n numbers in, say, 5*n^3 time) an NP-complete problem?

To me, it seems practically impossible that the problem is in P: If you had the level of understanding of algorithms required to show quickly that all algorithms smaller than this-or-that size will produce a different output or require more than 5*n^3 time, what reasons could there be that prevent you from having the level of understanding required to solve the Halting problem? (in this case, actually, the problem of determining whether a program will run in less than 5*n^3 steps) But I have no clue how you could possibly *prove* this. On the one hand, this seems to be for exactly the same reason: If you use the method "cleverly encode your SAT problem as a pattern; then prove that if the SAT instance is satisfiable, you could use a Turing machine of form A; if it is not satisfiable, you must use a longer Turing machine of form B" (or vice versa), how do you want to show that there exists no Turing machine C that is smaller than both of them? And: If you had the understanding to prove that, how could you possibly not be able to solve the Halting problem?

Even if you left that issue aside, I can't even think of approaches that could create such an A-B dichotomy.

Is the problem possibly NP-intermediate?

Comment: In order for a problem to be NP-complete or NP-intermediate, it has to itself be in NP. Do you have reason to believe this problem is in NP? I'm not entirely convinced that it's even computable...

Comment: 'Pattern Recognition' seems too general a name for this problem. It sounds more like interpolation.

Comment: Perhaps the time bound (like 5*n^3) should be in terms of the total length (in digits) of the desired output rather than in terms of n.  That way, with a reasonable bound, there will be some program producing the right output (e.g., just a print command) and the problem is just to find the shortest one, as opposed to having to worry about whether such a program exists at all.  

Comment: If you formulate the problem as "Given a list of n numbers and bounds k and t, does there exist a Turing machine of size at most k which outputs these numbers in time at most t?" then the problem will be in NP: the proof certificate is just the Turing machine, which we simulate for time t to check that it outputs the desired numbers.

Comment: You cannot afford "to simulate it for time $t$" if $t\gg n$. 

Comment: But nibbles specified that $t$ is polynomial in $n$. (He gave $5n^3$ as a possible $t$.) 

Comment: Right now, I realize that my original problem formulation was incoherent due to speed-up theorems. I will constrain myself to a finite alphabet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key phrase you are looking for is "**resource-bounded Kolmogorov complexity**". [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.150.9495) by Allender, et. al. may be a good starting point. Also, [this PhD thesis](http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~troyjlee/thesis.html) might provide some helpful background.

*Edited to add*:

According to the first article, [Ko, K.-I. "On the complexity of learning minimum time-bounded Turing machines", *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 20 (1991)](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=92591) may be even more relevant. In that paper, Ko demonstrates that determining whether or not computing time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity is NP-hard requires non-relativizing techniques.